# npm start throwing error while starting on react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

While running `npm start` command, I'm getting following error:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: watch /home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/public ENOSPC
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:232:14)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:414:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:462:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:467:16)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ruchit/.npm/_logs/2018-12-15T15_05_28_201Z-debug.log
```

As mentioned in blogs with similar issue, I implemented all suggestions like `updating npm / node, install yarn, install watchman` etc etc. None of above is working. I'm adding complete log of this process:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v8.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~prestart: myapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: myapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp/node_modules/.bin:/home/ruchit/bin:/home/ruchit/.local/bin:/home/ruchit/bin:/home/ruchit/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp
10 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid myapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ruchit/codes/react/myapp
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.5.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please suggest me how to go about solving this ? Should I re-install create-react-app ? I'm using `ubuntu 16.04.`

Comment: even changing port is not working out!

Comment: try using this solution https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3254#issuecomment-297214395

Comment: @Eugene Thanks! This worked :)